# Cannot delete hidden file on network drive using DOS / batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to delete a file from a mapped network drive, `I:`

In my batch script, I have:

```
del /f I:\bin\.hiddenfile
```

When I run the script, I go to the directory `I:\bin` and see that `.hiddenfile` is still there.

Now I use the command prompt and change directories to `I:\bin`. When I issue `dir -a`, I see `.hiddenfile`, but when I issue `del .hiddenfile`, I receive the error

```
Could Not Find I:\bin\.hiddenfile
```

How can I remove this file?

**edit:** Solved by changing the script as follows:

```
del /a /f I:\bin\.hiddenfile
```

Thanks for the help! In case anyone's wondering, I didn't explicitly make the file hidden - I create it in Unix just as ".hiddenfile" and in Windows, it shows up as "hidden".

Comment: `rm` is a unix command not a windows command try `del`

Comment: @50-3 Sorry, habit. In the batch script I have `del` actually... still the problem persists.

Comment: It's showing up as hidden because it starts with a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify that you're intentionally deleting a hidden file.

```
del /AH .hiddenfile
```

should do the trick.

See the output of `del /?` for details.

`dir` follows the same pattern, by the way. So you can see hidden files with `dir /AH`.

Comment: Yer you were correct miss read it as directory not file, probably got lost as he didn't declare it was a file with the hidden attribute :)

Comment: Actually, I was able to fix this by just adding the `/a` flag to `del`. I'm not sure if there's some hidden file switch in the Windows filesystem. It's a file that I create in Unix and just read it through a mapped network drive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `-s` and `-h` attributes from the file with an `attrib -s -h .hiddenfile` before deleting.